# know when user clicks on rate and review?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-store, charms-bar

Is there any way I can know that a user clicked on the Rate & Review button in the charms/settings bar?
**Note:** This button is automatically added to Apps in the Windows Store. I don't have any control over the button.

I thought that it would be ideal to show a message explaining to them that they shouldn't use the rate and review button for support requests since we cannot respond to that.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava That has nothing to do with the Windows Charms bar and the Windows store ratings.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, but you could use something similar to SO that notifies the user to log in or sign up when an unregistered user wants to vote a post up or down.

```
 <div id='message' style="display: none;"> 
    <span>Hey, This is my Message.</span> 
    <a href="#" class="close-notify">X</a> 
 </div> 


#message { 
        font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
        position:fixed; 
        top:0px; 
        left:0px; 
        width:100%; 
        z-index:105; 
        text-align:center; 
        font-weight:bold; 
        font-size:100%; 
        color:white; 
        padding:10px 0px 10px 0px; 
        background-color:#8E1609; 
    } 

    #message span { 
        text-align: center; 
        width: 95%; 
        float:left; 
    } 

    .close-notify { 
        white-space: nowrap; 
        float:right; 
        margin-right:10px; 
        color:#fff; 
        text-decoration:none; 
        border:2px #fff solid; 
        padding-left:3px; 
        padding-right:3px 
    } 

    .close-notify a { 
        color: #fff; 
    } 

    // And this is javascript (using jQuery):
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#message").fadeIn("slow"); 
        $("#message a.close-notify").click(function() { 
            $("#message").fadeOut("slow"); 
            return false; 
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: thanks but my issue is not what to do when the user clicks ratings & review but how to know when the user does that.